# Connect XPage with OpenOffice

Tags: xpages, openoffice.org, uno

I have a button on an XPage where I want to connect to a remote OpenOffice instance. OpenOffice is started and is listening for a socket connection.

The onclick event of the button runs following SSJS:

```
    oo = new com.test.OpenOffice();
    oo.init("host=127.0.0.1,port=8107");
    oo.openFile("C:\\TEMP\\Test.odt");
```

The code raises an excepction `jva.lang.IlleagalStateException: NotesContext not initialized for the thread`

The exception is raised within the method `init`of the class `OpenOffice`.

The relevant parts of the class OpenOffice is the following code:

```
public class DHOpenOffice implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7443191805456329135L;
    private XComponentContext xRemoteContext;
    private XMultiComponentFactory xMCF;
    private XTextDocument oTextDocument;

    public DHOpenOffice() {
        xRemoteContext = null;
        xMCF = null;
        oTextDocument = null;
    }   

    public void init(String hostAdr) throws java.lang.Exception {
        xRemoteContext = null;

        XComponentContext xLocalContext = Bootstrap.createInitialComponentContext(null);
        XUnoUrlResolver xUrlResolver = UnoUrlResolver.create(xLocalContext);

        String sConnect = "uno:socket," + hostAdr + ",tcpNoDelay=0;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager";

        Object context = xUrlResolver.resolve(sConnect);
        xRemoteContext = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XComponentContext.class, context);  
        xMCF = xRemoteContext.getServiceManager();  
    }
```

The code line `Object context = xUrlResolver.resolve(sConnect);` is the one that raises the exception.

Why is this happing? What is the reason for this exception and how can I resolve the situation?

N.B.: The class code runs smoothly in a standalone application. The error occurs only when the code is started by a SSJS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of @stwissel I was able to solve the problem (he pointed me to the right direction).

I could solve the problem with a simple OSGI plug-in. The servlet approach solved the problem, too, but for me the OSGI plug-in was easier to use.

So these are the steps to create the plug-in

- start a new plugin project
- copy the open office jar files into the project and include them into the build path
- copy the custom class that uses the UNO API into the plug-in
- create a feature project for the plugin
- create an update site
- deploy the plugin via an update site

The following site where also quite helpfull:

- [Creating an XPages Library](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_an_XPages_Library)
- [Wrap an existing JAR file into a plug-in](http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/wrap-an-existing-jar-file-into-a-plug-in)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a threading issue. There are a number of things you can go and try:

- Wrap the whole interaction into a custom class and use it from a managed bean instead of calling it from SSJS
- Make sure not to hand over any Notes objects into the custom class, only your own
- Check if the [Open Document Toolkit](https://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/) would be sufficient to do the operations you are interested in, so you don't need to run OO

let us know how it goes

***Update***
Try to get outside the standard XPages cycle. One way is to deploy a custom plug-in servlet:

```
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class OpenOfficeServlet extends HttpServlet {
   // Your code goes here
}
```

You need to get the plugin.xml right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets">
         <servlet alias="/ooproxy" class="com.yourcompany.OpenOfficeServlet" />
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

Then you could e.g. post a JSON structure or a serializable Java object to the servlet with the data and process it there (async if necessary). You deploy such a plug-in using the updatesite.nsf

Comment: I've put the class DHOpenOffice into a managed bean and called the methods of the managed bean. The result is the same: an exception stating NotesContext not initialized. No Notes objects are handed over. The ODFToolkit is no option because it is missing some functions I must use. Maybe this information is helping to track down the problem: the exceptions is raised in the thread "MessageDispatcher"

Comment: The OO Java package uses threads that interfere with the XPages lifecycle. It seems you need to separate that further. I found that an XPages servlet or an XPages custom Rest service did not inherit the session/context so you could succeed there. Not pretty

Comment: Bypass the XPages lifecycle using a servlet run in a plug-in.

Comment: I'll give the servlet a try and will report how it is going.

Comment: I've create the servlet and deployed it to the server. Everythins is fine until I instantiate my custom class to connect to OO. The constructor is simply initializing some class properties. But calling the constructor results in a HTTP 500 error. In the error log I can find the follwing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.star.connection.NoConnectException`. Any hints what's going wrong?

Comment: Are the classes inside your plugin